# onclick to show <p><h1><iframe> , function showHide(shID)

Tags: javascript, onclick, show-hide

I had done a onclick showHide function , but only show 1 element in a section .when people click on read more button will show paragraph and also video or some images .
How can I onclick to show headline,paragraph and also iframe?.
Thanks for help !

```
<style type="text/css">
   /* This CSS is used for the Show/Hide functionality. */
   .more {
      display: none;
      border-top: 1px solid #666;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #666; }
   a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #36f;
      padding-left: 8px;
      background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.hideLink {
      background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left; }
   a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; }
</style>



<div id="wrap">
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');">
<button class="btn-u btn-u-lg btn-block btn-u-dark-orange">
Read More
</button>
</a>
<div id="example" class="more">
<iframe width="600" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/BaPlMMlyM_0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
</div>
</div>  

<!-- Hide Function -->           
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code works just fine: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a75985pg/). If you are testing on localhost or localfile then mind the protocol you are using. In iFrame src you have `src="//www.youtube..." `.  Change it to `src="http://www.youtube..." `.

Comment: Hi Nomeaning25 . thanks for telling me that , i review and tested again it works now . =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the wrong element: `shID+'-show' = 'example-show'`, this id is is not the of the hidden div. This is a working version of what I think you want to achieve.

```js
function showHide(shID) {
  var hiddenDiv = document.getElementById(shID);
  if ( hiddenDiv ) {
    if (hiddenDiv.style.display !== 'none') {
      hiddenDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
      hiddenDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* This CSS is used for the Show/Hide functionality. */
.more {
  display: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #666; 
}
a.showLink, a.hideLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #36f;
  padding-left: 8px;
  background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; 
}
a.hideLink {
  background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left;
}
a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');">
    <button class="btn-u btn-u-lg btn-block btn-u-dark-orange">
      Read More
    </button>
  </a>
  <div id="example" class="more">
    <iframe width="600" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/BaPlMMlyM_0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>Congratulations! You've found the magic hidden text! Clicking the link below will hide this content again.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```